# How to use Networks(python) draw method?

Tags: python, draw

My code as follows:

```
import ConfigParser
import sys
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx
import json
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite

def create_graph(senators):

    G= nx.Graph()

    G.add_nodes_from(senators)

    return G
senators=["ab","cd","ef"]
graph = create_graph(senators)
nx.draw(graph,with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("p1.png")



graph.clear()
graph = nx.DiGraph()
print graph.nodes()


nx.draw(graph,with_labels=True)
plt.savefig("p2.png")
```

In my code I try to draw two pictures:p1.png  and p2.png. After I draw p1.png , I clear graph. However, p2.png  has the same node with p1.png.

I don't know what's wrong with my code . Because I have clear graph, so there should be nothing in p2.png

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are two separate notions of "clearing".  One is removing nodes and edges from the graph (graph.clear) and the other is erasing the figure (plt.clf()).  You are removing the nodes and edges but  not clearing the figure axes.  So what you are saving in p2.png is just the original p1.png figure.  Try adding a plt.clf() before the second nx.draw().